# Display and modify JSON data (displayed in table ) Using React JS

Tags: css, json, reactjs, html-table

I am very new to React to JS and also this is my first question to the community so please help me.

I want to create a table which will display the data from a JSON file (it should display some 50 rows per page), also I need the capability to modify the data in the same table and later update the contents of the JSON accordingly.

I need to have the following types of cells in the table: Normal uneditable text box, editable text box, Select Lists (showing data from another JSON file), Number fields, calendar, etc..

I know it might feel like a stupid question to many of you but please help me understand how to approach this problem.

*(I am not asking for working code, please help me on how to get started with it.)*

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For table :
1. Create a component
2. Store the json value in state.
3. construct table. In tbody use state.map and return rows.

For uneditable text-box make it read-only.

Answer (score 2):

Tons of libraries on github can do what you need.

For example:

- https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/
- https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table
- https://material-ui.com/demos/tables/

There are many many others, which one should be used is based on your detail requirement and then find the best fit.